# How to check if byte[] contains only zeros?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

How can I check if a byte[] contains only 0's?  I do not want to send the array over the network if it only contains zeroes:

```
byte[] bytesToBeSend = e.GetAudioSamples;

// Send test data to the remote device.
Send(client, bytesToBeSend);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Insert this test before your `Send` request and use an `if` test:

```
bool hasAllZeroes = bytesToBeSend.All(singleByte => singleByte == 0);

if (!hasAllZeroes) {
    Send(client, bytesToBeSend);
}
```

Make sure that you've included LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Note that delegates (lambda expressions) are quite slow. Using a foreach loop to test array elements would have higher performance, but lambda code is more readable.

Answer (score 8):

One option is to check every byte equal to zero, but we can check for non zero byte exist or not. then if that true we can send. this will be fast.

```
if(bytesToBeSend.Any(b => b!=0))
  Send(client, bytesToBeSend);
```